# Oracle - Why must constraint_name be unique if owned by a different schema?

Tags: oracle, constraints, schema, ownership

In Oracle, if you try to explicitly define the schema for a constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` statement it will result in a `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` error:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA1.MY_TABLE
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(5)
, FLAG VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'F'
, CONSTRAINT SCHEMA1.MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_ID)  -- Parser doesn't like 'SCHEMA1'
, CONSTRAINT SCHEMA1.MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK CHECK (FLAG IN ('T', 'F')) --Same issue
);
```

This is no big deal because the constraint `OWNER` defaults to the same schema as defined in the `CREATE TABLE` declaration (*or at least in the schema you are signed into - my accounts don't have the rights to validate*). This can be confirmed by pulling up the constraint in `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` or `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` and viewing the `OWNER` value (which would read `SCHEMA1` for the two constraints above).

But if you then follow up this statement with a second duplicate statement under a different schema:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA2.MY_TABLE
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(5)
, FLAG VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'F'
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_ID)          --This constraint already exists
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK CHECK (FLAG IN ('T', 'F')) --This one too
);
```

this results in an `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` error.

My understanding of constraints are that they are just another object on the database which I would have assumed were subject to the same ownership rules with which I'm familiar. But based on the behavior above it is clear that they do not behave like most objects on the database.

**Questions**

- What is it about constraints that requires their names be unique across all schemas (unlike other objects on the database)?
- Does anyone know the technical reason for this naming requirement?

---

**For context**, I've run into a scenario at work where I had wanted to store duplicate names under different schemas (don't ask... it was inherited duplication and I'm just trying to stay consistent until I have funding to refactor). Now, I realize that I can very simply add the schema to the name and bypass this problem quickly but this rubs my OCD the wrong way so I'd like to better understand just why I can't do what I'm trying to do.

**----------------------------- UPDATE ---------------------------**

Okay... so I'm a fool. Please note that the above scenario **cannot be repeated** given a clean environment. After trying to reproduce the issue, I now realize what happened.

I'm currently working on cleaning up some DDL statements in preparation for a production release. I'm not the only developer in this environment and my offshore team has been working on these same tables. I have been editing some preexisting DDL scripts in preparation for a production release and had added some needed constraints to a few `CREATE TABLE` statements.

It would appear that I had failed to run my `DROP` scripts before running the second statement in `SCHEMA2`.  My confusion was due to thinking that I was getting the `ORA-00955` error because of the new constraints I was adding when in actuality it was because the `SCHEMA2.MY_TABLE` already existed in this environment. This misdiagnosis was compounded by me changing my constraint names and then rerunning all of my scripts successfully (as I must have run my `DROP` statements in all schemas before retesting). As a result I thought that I had observed unforeseen behavior when I really had not.

Thank you to everyone who commented for showing me the light!

Comment: It's not so - you **can** create constraints with the same names in different schemas.  So not sure what you are doing - I didn't really understand when you said "_(or at least in the schema you are signed into - my accounts don't have the rights to validate)_".

Comment: Was about to comment the same thing as we have instances with mutliple developer accounts with identical tables / constraints. It all works cleanly if you are properly signed in under the schema you are creating it in.

Comment: I'm away from my DB, but is it possible there is a glitch where including the constraint creation inside the create table defaults the ownership to the signed-in user rather than the schema identified for the table? That could cause a collision, but could be resolved by making the constraint a separate create statement. I always do my creates signed in as the correct schema, so haven't ever hit this issue..

Comment: @TonyAndrews - Hmm... I just tried a different test and you are absolutely right... Now I'm really scratching my head... Let me look back through my original scripts and I'll update the post as soon as I can recreate what I was seeing before.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Thanks for your comment... I think I know what happened and have updated my question.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Thanks for your comment... this was definitely a glitch but not on Oracle... I've chalked this up to user error on my part and have attached an explanation of what I think happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's missing in your question is the user under which you run the script. But here's a little experiment.
Connected to the database as user system. I have schemas NGM42 and NGM41 available for the experiment.

```
CREATE TABLE NGM41.MY_TABLE
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(5)
, FLAG VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'F'
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_ID)  -- Parser doesn't like 'SCHEMA1'
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK CHECK (FLAG IN ('T', 'F')) --Same issue
);

CREATE TABLE NGM42.MY_TABLE
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(5)
, FLAG VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'F'
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_ID)  
, CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK CHECK (FLAG IN ('T', 'F')) 
);
```

Both statements run succesfully. So what happened to the constraints?

```
select owner,constraint_name from all_constraints
where constraint_name in ('MY_TABLE_PK','MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK')

NGM42   MY_TABLE_PK
NGM41   MY_TABLE_PK
NGM41   MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK
NGM42   MY_TABLE_FLAG_CK
```

The constraints are created in the same schema as the table. As you can see they do not need to be globally unique in the database.

Comment: Thanks for this answer... it is dead on. It would appear that my environment was not clean before I tried to run my second statement. My `ORA-00955` was due to the table already existing not the constraint.